# Unable to enable filestream filegroup in Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server Database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 database project type for managing the DB scripts. I need the file stream file-group to be configured during the creation of the database. However in the database settings (VS 2012) I am not able to select the "**Default FileStream FileGroup**".

[image]

My initial guess why this problem might be happening is that I have configured "e:\" on my machine as default datapath and this is an ex-FAT partition. The filestream filegroup can be configured only on an NTFS partion as per the documentation.

Is there any way I can just enable this option so that I can point to a proper NTFS folder?

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually add a filestream filegroup to your project and build it before you can set this option.

In your project, click Add new item, choose to add a new filegroup and edit the code so it looks something like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILEGROUP [FileStream_FileGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM
```

Build the project, then go into database settings again and you will be able to select this filegroup as the default filestream filegroup.  You are right though, when adding your filestream file to this filegroup it will have to be on an NTFS volume.

Comment: I am using the database project type to automate end to end deployment. So I was hoping that this would be some kind of setting. I have now created a pre-deployment script to add filegroup for filestream and also configure the file for the filestream grouping